# Why issue in Duo Web SDK for Text.Json package?

Tags: sharepoint

Error Message : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Error Source : DuoUniversal
This is the error. I have already added the Text.Json to GAC

I try to degrade the version. But its not possible due to version incompitable with DuoUniversal version

Comment: Do you see where the incorrect version is being imported?

Comment: I have download and added dll with same version to the solution